# myBatis Spring Boot Collection tag

Tags: collections, mybatis

I am currently working on a project that uses Spring Boot and myBatis. My problem is, I have a List of ObjectB inside ObjectA.

Using resultMap mapping, I am able to get values for the fields of ObjectA but the  tag seems to not retrieve a list of ObjectB

```
class ObjectA {
   pritvate int id;
   private String someString;
   private List<ObjectB> listB;

   //getters and setters
}

class ObjectB {
   private String title;
   private String somefield;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Currently, I'm using JOINS, my syntax for the myBatis mappers in the XML is correct as I can retrieve data for ObjectA but not retrieve a list of ObjectB.

I tried my SQL and it works.

Comment: UPDATE: The Collection populates data when using Nested Select method but when using the JOIN method, it does not

Comment: Please, provide xml mapping for the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Seems like there was an issue with the mapping when you use a custom getter for your properties.